# Error: 18456 State 5 when attempting to connect to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

When I attempt to access a database using SQL Server Management Studio using Windows Server 2016 and the default Windows Administrator account, I am getting the error above.

The state of this error suggests that it "could not find a login matching the name provided"

Access has been achieved in the past, but since the Administrator password has been changed, this is no longer working. No other users on the machine in question are able to login and are getting the same error.

Is there any way I can regain access to the system using Windows Auth?

Comment: Is SQL Authentication turned on and is the `sa` account active?

Comment: Local administrator is not automatically added as a SQL Server login anymore, since 2012 or maybe even earlier? You have to explicitly add them (there is a chance to do this during setup, and you have to add someone, but obviously in this case it was a different Windows account). Assuming this is the local instance, see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/argenis_fernandez/archive/2012/01/12/leveraging-service-sids-to-logon-to-sql-server-2012-instances-with-sysadmin-privileges.aspx

Comment: Are you using the `Local Server Admin account` or the `Domain Admin account`? If it's Windows Authentication, then it shouldn't matter if the password changed or not, if you've used this account in the past to authenticate into SQL.

Comment: Server is set to only allow Windows Authentication and the sa account is not active.

Comment: Using the Local Server Admin account. I did not set it up personally but I believe it was configrued to use this account during set up.

Comment: There is no way that a password change would cause "could not found a login" - either you were using a different Windows auth account before, or they have been removed (and it might have been a role that was removed, they might never have been granted explicit access as an individual login).

Comment: It doesn't matter how it was set up, once you have regained access you can easily verify how it's set up now in sys.server_principals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve the issue by signing in as a single user using the instructions here - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004(v=sql.110).aspx

Once in, I discovered that the name of the machine had been changed at some point, therefore the local admin account was attempting to sign in using the wrong domain.